# How to enumerate with a reference to the previous element, in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: elixir, enumeration

I need to normalize a list of elements before applying `Enum.chunk_by` to the list.

Typically when we enumerate we go item by item, for example

```
source_list |> normalize_item
```

How may we enumerate while referencing previous element in the list?

Also, how may we keep a reference to the last normalized_item on the next iteration?

Sample Data:

```
[
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 91, page: 13, row: 237, start: 48, text: "2348035250601"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 155, page: 13, row: 237, start: 99, text: "17-12-2014 10:08:32"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 247, page: 13, row: 238, start: 168, text: "1080643204171320 2811630"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 286, page: 13, row: 238, start: 268, text: "400.00"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 394, page: 13, row: 238, start: 370, text: "Payment"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 91, page: 13, row: 244, start: 48, text: "2348035250601"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 155, page: 13, row: 244, start: 99, text: "17-12-2014 10:09:12"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 247, page: 13, row: 246, start: 168, text: "1775292204171752 2811630"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 286, page: 13, row: 246, start: 268, text: "400.00"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 394, page: 13, row: 246, start: 370, text: "Payment"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 91, page: 13, row: 252, start: 48, text: "2348068014410"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 155, page: 13, row: 252, start: 99, text: "17-12-2014 08:34:23"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 250, page: 13, row: 254, start: 168, text: "174729900817063 100153465"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 286, page: 13, row: 254, start: 263, text: "1,500.00"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 394, page: 13, row: 254, start: 370, text: "Payment"}
]
```

I need to normalize the `row` fields above, where two adjacent elements are actually on the same row, if their difference is `<= 2`, before applying `Enum.chunk_by` to the list

I have considered `Enum.chunk_while` but it does not offer a good solution in this case.

Expected output:

```
[
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 91, page: 13, row: 237, start: 48, text: "2348035250601"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 155, page: 13, row: 237, start: 99, text: "17-12-2014 10:08:32"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 247, page: 13, row: 237, start: 168, text: "1080643204171320 2811630"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 286, page: 13, row: 237, start: 268, text: "400.00"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 394, page: 13, row: 237, start: 370, text: "Payment"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 91, page: 13, row: 244, start: 48, text: "2348035250601"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 155, page: 13, row: 244, start: 99, text: "17-12-2014 10:09:12"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 247, page: 13, row: 244, start: 168, text: "1775292204171752 2811630"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 286, page: 13, row: 244, start: 268, text: "400.00"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 394, page: 13, row: 244, start: 370, text: "Payment"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 91, page: 13, row: 252, start: 48, text: "2348068014410"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 155, page: 13, row: 252, start: 99, text: "17-12-2014 08:34:23"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 250, page: 13, row: 252, start: 168, text: "174729900817063 100153465"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 286, page: 13, row: 252, start: 263, text: "1,500.00"},
%PhoneBills.Text{end: 394, page: 13, row: 252, start: 370, text: "Payment"}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest most straightforward approach would be to use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3). Unfortunately, I was unable to parse the requirements on how exactly you want to mutate `row`, but here is a generic example:

```rb
Enum.reduce(source_list, %{last: nil, values: []}, fn e, acc ->
  %{last: e, values: acc.values ++ [e]}
end)
```

Also, [`Enum.chunk_while/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_while/4) is also a good candidate to do the job. If you could produce the expected output, I might come out with an example of `chunk_while` application.

---

```rb
defmodule PhoneBills.Text,
  do: defstruct ~w|end page row start text|a

input = [...]

Enum.reduce(input, %{row: 0, acc: []}, fn e, acc ->        
  row = if e.row - acc.row <= 2, do: acc.row, else: e.row    
  %{row: row, acc: acc.acc ++ [%PhoneBills.Text{e | row: row}]}
end)
```

---

The solution with `Enum.chunk_while/4`:

```rb
chunk_fun = fn
  e, %{row: 0, acc: acc} -> # init
    {:cont, %{acc: [e], row: e.row}}
  %{row: e_row} = e, %{row: row, acc: acc} when e_row - row > 2 -> # emit
    {:cont, acc, %{row: e_row, acc: [e]}}
  e, %{row: row, acc: acc} -> # continue collecting
    {:cont, %{row: row, acc: acc ++ [%PhoneBills.Text{e | row: row}]}}
end

after_fun = fn
  %{acc: []} -> {:cont, []}
  %{acc: acc} -> {:cont, acc, []}
end

Enum.chunk_while(input, %{row: 0, acc: []}, chunk_fun, after_fun)
```

That way the output is already both *adjusted* and *chunked*.

**EDIT:**
Solution accounting for page numbers: [actual test data](https://gist.github.com/CharlesOkwuagwu/a73ee960c110124d19ca984a05e3fee3)

```rb
chunk_fun = fn
  # init
  e, %{page: 0, row: 0, acc: acc} ->
    {:cont, %{acc: [e], page: e.page, row: e.row}}

   # emit - while on same page, or on different page
  %{row: e_row, page: e_page} = e, %{page: page, row: row, acc: acc}
  when e_page == page and e_row - row > 2 or e_page != page ->
    {:cont, acc, %{page: e_page, row: e_row, acc: [e]}}

  # continue collecting
  e, %{page: page, row: row, acc: acc} ->
    {:cont, %{page: page, row: row, acc: acc ++ [%Text{e | row: row, page: page}]}}
end

after_fun = fn
  %{acc: []} -> {:cont, []}
  %{acc: acc} -> {:cont, acc, []}
end

Enum.chunk_while(input, %{row: 0, page: 0, acc: []}, chunk_fun, after_fun)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added the expected output. The code is for PDF to text extraction using `System.cmd("gswin64c", ["-sDEVICE=txtwrite", "-dTextFormat=0", "-o", dst, src])`

Comment: FWIW, I have posted the solution with `chunk_while/4` that both adjusts **and** chunks in one iteration.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have tried a modified version of your `chunk_while` solution that also accounts for the page number. Somehow, the result seems incorrect. This is a link to the actual data: https://gist.github.com/CharlesOkwuagwu/a73ee960c110124d19ca984a05e3fee3

Comment: Why do you use `===` in page comparison?

Comment: Also, I suspect you want to _emit_ not only on the same page.

Comment: I just caught that now :) i needed a second emit!

Comment: pages are integer type ... and i expect a Boolean result ... I thought that calls for  `===`

Comment: `===` only differs from `==` that [it does not coerce values](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#===/2) (`1.0 === 1` ⇒ `false`,) but in your case there are two integers so no need for `===`.

Comment: `e_page == page and e_row - row > 2 or e_page != page`?